# How to add users and add them to groups in linux bash

Tags: users, useradd

```
sudo adduser –G {teacher} user
sudo adduser –G {teacher} user
```

How could I fix this if *user* is an input variable and *teacher* is an existing group?

Comment: Linux is just an OS kernel found in a variety of completely different operating systems. What matters here is the OS (Debian, ChromeOS, Fedora, OpenWRT...) not so much the kernel.

Comment: so you want a script?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas useradd obviously exists in the OS in question as can be inferred from the question. What is not clear is whether teacher should be primary or supplementary group, whether sudo is required in the solution (which would imply adding useradd cmd to sudoers file) and whether this should be a script or an alias or bash function or something else (perhaps batch add a group of users to group teacher?).

Comment: @Dani_I, that was more of a note that the Linux tag or the linux reference in the subject were meaningless. There are several incompatible implementations of  `useradd`.

Answer (score 2):

First set a variable containing the username:

```
myUSER=user1
```

Then call the `adduser` script using:

```
sudo adduser --ingroup teacher "$myUSER"
```